# Use of interface to loosely couple NoSQL provider

Tags: c#, architecture, interface, dependency-injection

This is a bit of an idiot question, so you'll have to forgive me, but I'm a self-taught programmer and good, clean architecture often stumps me. I'm learning through questions like this one :)

So I have to code up a data access class to interact with a NoSQL database. The trouble is that at we want to leave ourselves open to changing our NoSQL platform at a later date so I need to make this dependency between my class and the actual data access as loose as possible.

Sketching this out in my head I figured the best way to do this was to make an interface a bit like this:

```
public interface INoSql
{
    string ServerLocation
    {
        get; set;
    }

    string DatabaseName
    {
        get; set;
    }

    string CollectionName
    {
        get; set;
    }

    void SaveChanges(List<NoSqlItem> nsCollection);
}
```

And then to make a specific data access class that would look like this for MongoDB

```
public class MongoDBConnection : IRealtimeDataAccess
{
    string ServerLocation
    {
        get; set;
    }

    string DatabaseName
    {
        get; set;
    }

    string CollectionName
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public void SaveChanges(List<NoSqlItem> nsCollection)
    {
        MongoServer mServer = MongoServer.Create(this.ServerLocation);
        MongoDatabase mDb = mServer.GetDatabase(this.DatabaseName);
        MongoCollection<BsonDocument> mDbItemCollection = mDb.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(this.CollectionName);
        mDbItemCollection.InsertBatch(nsCollection);
    }
```

Simple so far - all I have to do is make sure any class using the data access layer only references the interface and then if we want to swap out to another NoSQL provider all I have to do is re-code a new data access component implementing the same interface right? Well, thinking it through, the problem comes when I want to use it. Because this is obviously not going to work:

```
 INoSql noSQLConnection = new INoSql;
```

Because you can't instantiate an Interface.

So what's the solution to keep my code nice and loose? Reading around it looks as though one answer is to inject it into the constructor:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private INoSql NoSql;

     public myClass(INoSql NoSql)
     {
         this.NoSql = NoSql;
     }
 }
```

Which looks neat, but isn't this just displacing the problem? Because you're then going to have to instantiate a concrete version of something that implements INoSql when you create MyClass, yes, and that's going to have to be a MongoDBConnection - or whatever - instead of a loosely coupled class?

Obviously I've missed something, but what? And are there any other solutions to this common problem?

Cheers,
Matt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to re-invent the wheel.

In my humild opinion, **Repository design pattern** will do the job:

- http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx

**UPDATE**

I forgot the part of "how to get interface implementations".

You'd follow repository pattern, creating an interface or abstract class, later an specific implementation for your NoSQL object source.

In order to get the right implementation, as other have pointed out, you can use some frameworks like:

- Castle Windsor: http://www.castleproject.org/container/
- Ninject: http://ninject.org/
- Many others...

And, finally, I'd like to suggest you that *Common Service Locator* is a good friend in order to don't have a direct dependency to a particular IoC/DI framework:

- http://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks for this - interesting reading. In the end I decided that the Respository pattern was a bit overblown for my needs since the swap-out may never happen, and ideally I didn't want to add another external library to our code. I got most of what I needed with a factory method. However your answer is helpful, relevant and put me on the right path so deserves a tick.

Comment: @MattThrower No problem. By the way, you don't need to think about _repository pattern_ for "swapping-out". It's one of best solutions for absolutely abstract object source so you avoid dependencies to OR/M frameworks or just plain ADO.NET, and _repository pattern_ is more "business layer-friendly". But I don't know anything about your actual requirements and I hope this info could be a good source of inspiration in your future projects! :)

Answer (score 2):

Look into IoC containers, like [Castle Windsor](http://www.castleproject.org/container/), [SpringFramework.net](http://springframework.net), and [StructureMap](http://structuremap.net/structuremap/).  That the kind of problem that they are designed to solve.

Comment: Hey ;) But IoC solves retrieving the right implementation, but IoC itself isn't a solution for abstracting the object source.

Comment: Nevermind, I forgot the detail he's asking for how to get an implementation of some interface... Sorry :)

Comment: No, we encourage debate here, its fine.  IMHO, he is going to need something more sophisticated than just a repository pattern because (as @WillRogers points out), he also will need to tackle the problem of hard dependencies on the assemblies of the various drivers, and once you get into the problem of dynamically loading assemblies, it is better to leave it to the pros who have already solved the problem.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I've updated my own answer for covering this too.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Matias with regard to the Repository pattern. Another issue you're trying to tackle is taking a hard dependency on the db provider (MongoDB in your example). Although truly being able to swap out your data access is rarely as easy as hiding it behind an interface, a technique to do so is called dependency injection, and you're using a form of it (constructor injection) in your MyClass code.

Here's an overview on dependency injection: http://jamesshore.com/Blog/Dependency-Injection-Demystified.html

You're correct that it pushes the problem of the hard dependency out of the class to somewhere else. Luckily there are tools to help us wire-up and manage these dependencies that we later want to inject and use. These are know as Inversion of Control Containers, and they allow you to specify and resolve dependencies in code and often in config files. Here's an SO question regarding them:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515124/whats-the-simplest-ioc-container-for-c

Autofac, StructureMap, and Unity are some I've used with success.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You could use Unity or another IoC container to register and instantiate objects that implement interfaces. Your code would look something like:

```
INoSql noSQLConnection = UnityContainer.Resolve<INoSql>();
```

[Microsoft Unity Framework](http://unity.codeplex.com/)